# Strange Bittorrent Log On My Server

Tags: nginx, log-files, ubuntu-14.04

I don't know if the following log has something to do with my site being down sometime. I have lot of websites on my server and they don't have any logs like the following:

```
117.169.1.85 - - [03/Jan/2015:23:21:37 +0800] "GET /announce.php?info_hash=%D0%A2M%CE%13%21H%D4%11%0C%8C%27%22%C83%B4%A3l%92%15&peer_id=%2DSD0100%2D%C50%95xmh%9B%13%7C%D42%F7&ip=39.178.24.33&port=14940&uploaded=3893629&downloaded=3893629&left=1369695469&numwant=200&key=1490&compact=1 HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "Bittorrent"
115.231.228.252 - - [03/Jan/2015:23:21:37 +0800] "GET /announce.php?info_hash=%DE%82%BC%CFBmH%29e%FD%25%ED6b%F2%2DX%EE%BE%21&peer_id=%2DSD0100%2D%BF3%DAG%83%1F%DAGnV%E3%C8&ip=118.134.134.210&port=13567&uploaded=675282944&downloaded=675282944&left=80740352&numwant=200&key=7916&compact=1 HTTP/1.0" 404 162 "-" "Bittorrent"
115.231.228.252 - - [03/Jan/2015:23:21:37 +0800] "GET /announce?info_hash=%DE%82%BC%CFBmH%29e%FD%25%ED6b%F2%2DX%EE%BE%21&peer_id=%2DSD0100%2D%BF3%DAG%83%1F%DAGnV%E3%C8&ip=118.134.134.210&port=13567&uploaded=675282944&downloaded=675282944&left=80740352&numwant=200&key=16205&compact=1 HTTP/1.0" 404 20283 "-" "Bittorrent"
123.123.126.154 - - [03/Jan/2015:23:21:37 +0800] "GET /announce.php?info_hash=%AA%21U%8F%7F%BA%DC%8F%D2%A5%B5A%7B%26t%F7%2A%FF%1E%8C&peer_id=%2DSD0100%2D%91%11%E7%11G%7B%8C%EB%14Y%2B%26&ip=123.123.126.154&port=12070&uploaded=129742857&downloaded=129742857&left=85310&numwant=200&key=11590&compact=1 HTTP/1.0" 404 162 "-" "Bittorrent"
114.86.129.8 - - [03/Jan/2015:23:21:37 +0800] "GET /announce.php?info_hash=%9A%90s%DCK%29%93%05%FE%BA%E6%D3%7D%03%12%25l%B0%B8k&peer_id=%2DSD0100%2D%20%80%3FRw%E5%0E%3D%3F%2F%B1%0F&ip=114.86.129.8&port=17767&uploaded=240822656&downloaded=240822656&left=480772096&numwant=200&key=5792&compact=1 HTTP/1.0" 404 162 "-" "Bittorrent"
222.161.198.228 - - [03/Jan/2015:23:21:38 +0800] "GET /announce.php?info_hash=f%F7x%23%A6w%96%955%E6T%09%3Br%DD%A5%F3%3D%A4%05&peer_id=%2DSD0100%2Dp%83%F6%00%E9%04B4%28%E5%F4%F8&ip=192.168.1.102&port=11274&uploaded=444858368&downloaded=444858368&left=181403648&numwant=200&key=17766&compact=1 HTTP/1.0" 404 162 "-" "Bittorrent"
117.140.8.11 - - [03/Jan/2015:23:21:38 +0800] "GET /announce?info_hash=%C7Jr%2F%E4%DF9%ECk%BA%88%94%7B%FF%8Ad%102%FA%5B&peer_id=%2DSD0100%2D%F6%F1%A1%A6%C9%01%DC%17%DC%AA%5D%19&ip=19.34.33.71&port=16456&uploaded=60373348&downloaded=60373348&left=1712431046&numwant=200&key=31414&compact=1 HTTP/1.0" 499 0 "-" "Bittorrent"
60.242.213.36 - - [03/Jan/2015:23:21:38 +0800] "GET /announce?info_hash=%B3%DA%8D%13%F9n%5D%E3%00%F0f%19%8Fb%BA%FEgg%22%40&peer_id=%2DSD0100%2D%0F%F9%DC%2D%E3%A5%DB%CF%FE%09%AB%3C&ip=60.242.213.36&port=19859&uploaded=85983232&downloaded=85983232&left=1676673024&numwant=200&key=1997&compact=1 HTTP/1.0" 404 20283 "-" "Bittorrent"
61.183.79.192 - - [03/Jan/2015:23:21:38 +0800] "GET /announce?info_hash=%B3%DA%8D%13%F9n%5D%E3%00%F0f%19%8Fb%BA%FEgg%22%40&peer_id=%2DSD0100%2D%2D%A6%EF%F4%FCoe%C5%CB%A2%F8%15&ip=192.168.2.101&port=11136&uploaded=4194304&downloaded=4194304&left=1237319680&numwant=200&key=10639&compact=1 HTTP/1.0" 499 0 "-" "Bittorrent"
114.105.43.47 - - [03/Jan/2015:23:21:38 +0800] "GET /announce.php?info_hash=%B6%92n%10%AF%8F%8C%E7%7B1%F9%94%D9%1B%FB%2F%9F%E5%CF%13&peer_id=%2DSD0100%2D%B9N%C5%283%14%D0%C5%E7%96k%91&ip=114.105.43.47&port=13462&uploaded=1021732276&downloaded=1021732276&left=6291456&numwant=200&key=6618&compact=1 HTTP/1.0" 404 162 "-" "Bittorrent"
117.9.47.219 - - [03/Jan/2015:23:21:38 +0800] "GET /announce.php?info_hash=%A5u0%B1%BCC%05%CB%D0%97Ez%D6GX%1B%9E%D7%8C9&peer_id=%2DSD0100%2D%BD%2A%5E%D1%0E%ADZ%13%E0%1C%5F%1B&ip=117.9.47.219&port=14181&uploaded=787046358&downloaded=787046358&left=545&numwant=200&key=25770&compact=1 HTTP/1.0" 404 162 "-" "Bittorrent"
```

I tried to search this kind of log, but there's so little information about this.

I don't install any bittorrent apps on my server and wondering why it seems that my server is acting like a tracker.

Can anyone please help me why I have these kind of log?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesnt look like anything to worry about.  Bittorrent trackers are just regular HTTP servers.

Your server is sending 404 errors - there is no tracker on your server.

Probably at some point in the past your IP address was used as a tracker, or someone else has misconfigured their client, or their tracker dns.

Comment: Actually it looks that there might something bigger at play here. I get the same requests on 4 (that I am aware of) unrelated servers. I posted a question on how to block these requests via mod_security explaining a bit my findings on the subject http://serverfault.com/questions/656093/mod-security-block-requests-by-http-host-header It looks like a DNS Cache Poisoning by a Chinese ISP.

Comment: @Cha0s I think you are right. Until now, my server seems to suffer a down time sometimes because of this. Since I am using nginx, I don't think mod_security is the answer to my problem. Can you recommend any solution?

Comment: @jaypabs I mentioned my question to show my findings regarding those requests not being just some error in DNS or the IP being used as a torrent tracker in the past. I personally ended up blocking China with iptables. Even with mod_security the connections were so many that they would fill up apache's connections. I don't have any solution regarding nginx specifically.

Comment: @Cha0s May I know the command you use to block it using iptables?

Comment: @jaypabs I am using CSF/LFD which allows to block whole countries by CC. http://configserver.com/cp/csf.html

Answer (score 0):

It might be some type of DDoS attack. Add this to your site's .htaccess to block them.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bittorrent [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://bittorrent.com [R,L]

Comment: If it were a DDOS attack, this would not help.  Your server will send a 302 response instead of 404, using roughly the same amount of traffic - plus now the CPU load of processing redirects.  At the very least, it should send a 301 redirect so well behaved clients consider it permanent.  And if it is a DDOS attack, the owners of bittorrent.com probably wont be too happy that you're passing it along to them...